# statistics over kth events

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Assuming a table with the following format

```
Team   Score
----   -----
A       10
B       20
A       30
B       40
A       50
C       60
```

I would like to compute statistics, e.g. mean over the "kth" game a given team played, e.g. if k = 1, the mean is `(10 + 20 + 60) / 3`. How can one accomplish this using big query?  Is there a much  simpler way for special case k=1 vs. general case?

Comment: `SELECT *, avg(Score) over (partition by TEAM order by YOURCOLUMN RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) FROM your_table`  your example misses a column to order the events, such as a date column.

Comment: @Samuel note that the avg should be over the ```kth``` game played by teams.

Answer (score 2):

Consider below - it assumes you have column that represents game number or game date - something that defines game order - in this example I use column named `game` but you should replace it with your column

```
select avg(score) avg_score from (
  select * from your_table
  qualify row_number() over(partition by team order by game) <= 1
)
```

Comment: have you tried?